# Autoware car following issue using Open Planner

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to do some field test using the Autoware 1.13 Release + Open Planner. I would like test the car following scenario. The leading vehicle is travelling at 3m/s. The ego-vehicle is controlled using the Autoware+open planner. The parameters used for local planning are as below:
[image: image description]
[image: image description]

The ego-vehicle did not try to maintain a safe car-following distance (I assume it will maintain a safe gap with the same velocity with the leading vehicle). Instead, It approached the leading vehicle and made a hard brake to a full stop. Here is a [video](https://youtu.be/2yrm69gn5dQ) showing the process (sorry for the low resolution).

I am using default values for Internal ACC parameters as shown below:
[image: image description]

And yes I am using pure pursuit to track the trajectory, the parameters used for pure pursuit are as below:
[image: image description]

Is this caused by improper setting of some parameters? Any comments and suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380395/autoware-car-following-issue-using-open-planner/) by [yougeyxt](https://answers.ros.org/users/75368/yougeyxt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2021-06-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yougeyxt](https://answers.ros.org/users/75368/yougeyxt/) on 2021-06-15**:
Hi @Hatem, could you please take a look on this? Thanks :)!

**Comment by [Hatem](https://answers.ros.org/users/41954/hatem/) on 2021-06-16**:
what is the value of "enableinternalACC" parameter?

what controller are you using? pure pursuit ?

**Comment by [yougeyxt](https://answers.ros.org/users/75368/yougeyxt/) on 2021-06-16**:
Hi @Hatem, I did not find the "enableinternalACC" parameter in the code (Am I using the right version of the open planner for Autoware 1.13 release?). But I find the "use_internal_acc" parameter and it is set as False. I have uploaded the screenshot of parameters regarding to Internal ACC parameters in the main content (it seems I cannot upload figures in the comment).

And yes, I am using pure pursuit to track the trajectory and the parameters used in pure pursuit is uploaded above.

Thanks :)

**Comment by [yougeyxt](https://answers.ros.org/users/75368/yougeyxt/) on 2021-06-16**:
Hi Hatem,

The line 627 and 657 in the file common/op_planner/src/DecisionMaker.cpp (I am using the branch [openplanner.1.13](https://github.com/hatem-darweesh/common/blob/openplanner.1.13/op_planner/src/DecisionMaker.cpp) seems should be commented out? Is these two lines causing problems? The two lines of code are: desiredVelocity = 0; //for CARLA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you set use_internal_acc to False, you shouldn't use pure pursuit, the stop go behavior is the expected behavior in this case. and you need to use another controller such as op_waypoint_follower.

if you want to use pure_pursuit, set use_internal_acc to True, and tune values (PushRatio, acceleration, deceleration) to adjust how smooth you want to follow other vehicles.

---

Originally posted by [Hatem](https://answers.ros.org/users/41954/hatem/) with karma: 443 on 2021-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yougeyxt](https://answers.ros.org/users/75368/yougeyxt/) on 2021-06-17**:
Got it! Could you please confirm that lines 627 and 657 in DecisionMaker.cpp should be commented out? It seems like a bug to me.

**Comment by [Hatem](https://answers.ros.org/users/41954/hatem/) on 2021-06-17**:
commenting them will raise another issue,

when you enable use_internal_acc "UpdateVelocityDirectlyToTrajectorySmooth" will be called and disabling it will lead to calling "UpdateVelocityDirectlyToTrajectory"

you can try to comment them and try, it is opensource !

**Comment by [yougeyxt](https://answers.ros.org/users/75368/yougeyxt/) on 2021-06-17**:
Sure thing, just want to double-check it :) thanks a lot for the detailed answer!